# How To Set window.open in pass php parameter(it's Not Working)

Tags: javascript

How To Set window.open in pass PHP parameter

```
window.open('print/retail_invoice.php?TrCode='<?php echo $TrCode ?>,'_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ended the quote before the URL. `....?TrCode='<?php ....` Try below code:

```
window.open('print/retail_invoice.php?TrCode=<?php echo $TrCode ?>','_blank');
```